# What's the advantage of using UIViewController as owner of xib?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Most of the time, owners of xib is a UIViewController.

I sort of use it my self.

Still I am confused why.

I suppose, the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear is kind of the main selling point.

Is that it?

What are the advantage of using UIViewController as owners of an XIB?

Comment: As opposed to *what* alternative class?

Comment: NSObject? Any other object? The UIView?

Comment: Most answers tell about the benefit of UIViewController. Few addresses why regular NSObject won't do. I guess that viewDidLoad event is the killer feature isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

A UIViewController object is the main way for views to appear within an iOS window.

Apple provides this as a fundamental, foundational building block (along with so many others) which you can use to build upon quickly and get your app out to market.

And when you subclass UIViewController, you're able to do lots of beautiful customizations which can be collected and eventually turned into (hopefully decent) products.  When you subclass a UIViewController, you need to set the "owner" of a XIB file to that subclassed view controller (e.g. ThioViewController), so that way the app knows what object (and user interface) is being instantiated.

Hopefully this isn't too super abstract of an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

First, spend a bit time to understand MVC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

This is the milestone of Objective-C (not only) development.

UIViewController is controller for all your views (inside this viewController). It provide starting point for you to create views on the screen, manipulate the views, handle actions from views etc.

You can create UIViewController programmatically.

XIB is representation of the screen which you can comfortably operate in Interface Builder to create and customize design of your application screen or one of the screens.

Since XIB represent the screen(view) it must be the controller which controls all the view on the screen  - UIViewController or UINavigationController or other type of controller depending of your needs.

Most of time you will subclass UIViewController and use it to achieve you goals.

UIViewController have several subclasses which inherit directly from it (UINavigationController, UITabBarController).

Also UIViewController hav several methods (some of them)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

and

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Parameters

animated
If YES, the view is being added to the window using an animation.
Discussion
This method is called before the receiver’s view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view. You can override this method to perform custom tasks associated with displaying the view. For example, you might use this method to change the orientation or style of the status bar to coordinate with the orientation or style of the view being presented. If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

Please check Apple documentation for more information

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html